# Callback From Activity on Cordova

Tags: java, android, cordova, callback, phonegap-plugins

I have an activity Called 'Signature' and i call it from CordovaPlugin;

Plugin.java

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
            CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException
    {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Signature.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    cordova.startActivityForResult(this,i,90);
}
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "activity result in plugin: requestCode(" + requestCode + "), resultCode(" + resultCode + ")");
        if(requestCode == 90) {
             if (resultCode == this.cordova.getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                 Bundle res = intent.getExtras();
                 String result = res.getString("results");
                 Log.d("FIRST", "result:"+result);
                 this.callbackContext
                 .success(result.toString());
             } else {
                 this.callbackContext.error("Error");
             }
     }
```

Signature.java

```
private void finishWithResult(String result,int status)
{
    Bundle conData = new Bundle();
    conData.putString("results", result);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtras(conData);
    setResult(status, intent);
    finish();
}
```

However when i call "cordova.startActivityForResult" function "onActivityResult" immediately invokes it self. I  cannot callback from Activity via finishWithResult. Any advices. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all there was some code missing(return-statement for *execute*-method) and you have to tell android/cordova-plugin to wait until there is a result sent back to your webview-app by using *NO_RESULT* and *setKeepCallback* of *PluginResult* otherwise cordova/android expects to get an result as soon as *execute*-method has finished:

Plugin.java:

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
            CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException
    {

    PluginResult r = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
    r.setKeepCallback(true);
    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(r);

    Intent i = new Intent(context, Signature.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    cordova.startActivityForResult(this,i,90);

    return true;

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    // here is your former code
    ...
    ...
    // at last call sendPluginResult 
    this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, result.toString()));

    // when there is no direct result form your execute-method use sendPluginResult because most plugins I saw and made recently (Reminder) prefer sendPluginResult to success/error
    // this.callbackContext.success(result.toString());
}
```

Have an example [here](https://github.com/shaithana/cordova-plugin-wezka-nativecamera/blob/master/src/android/NativeCameraLauncher.java)(for your plugin class) and [here](https://github.com/shaithana/cordova-plugin-wezka-nativecamera/blob/master/src/android/CameraActivity.java)(for your signature class).

And one of mine: [here](https://github.com/blauharley/Cordova-Reminder/blob/exp/src/android/ReminderLauncher.java) and [here](https://github.com/blauharley/Phonegap-AndroidPluginTest/blob/master/src/com/phonegap/plugintest/CameraPlugin.java).