# Call JavaScript from CordovaActivity

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing an Android app with Cordova. I have a custom BroadcastReceiver and I want to open the main (and the only one) CordovaActivity in `onReceive` method. It works properly.

Now, I need execute a Javascript function to decide which screen (html) show, based on the value of an intent's extra.

**MyBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String myExtra = intent.getStringExtra("myExtra");
      Intent toActivity = new Intent(context, MainCordovaActivity.class);
      toActivity.putExtra("myExtra", myExtra);
      context.startActivity(newActivity);
    }
```

**MainCordovaActivity.java**

```
    public class MainCordovaActivity extends CordovaActivity {
      public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
        super.onCreate(s);
        super.init();
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
        String myExtra = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myExtra");
        //Execute Javascript here
      }
}
```

How can I do that? Am I in the correct way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the callback to be able to invoke success/error callback functions after some time has passed within your plugin like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099912/callback-from-activity-on-cordova/29108349#29108349):

within some java class method:

```
PluginResult r = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
r.setKeepCallback(true);
callbackContext.sendPluginResult(r);

// assign callbackContext to class property named callbackContext 
this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
```

Then you can pass a string(for instance serialized *JSONObject*) into a new instance of *PluginResult* that is returned to your success/error functions as parameter value:

within some java class method:

```
JSONObject serialized = new JSONObject();

serialized.put("value",1234);

// use assigned class property callbackContext to send some data back to your success callback 
// because of PluginResult.Status.OK and by passing PluginResult.Status.ERROR you invoke error callback
this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, serialized));
```

Have a look [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/PluginResult.java) of what *PluginResult* accepts as parameters.

within your plugin.js file:

```
exec(function(serialized){ 
   console.log(serialized.value);// 1234
}, function(){}, "your plugin name", "your plugin action", { some_arg:'for your plugin'});
```