# How to call javascript function from android -Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

I'm using cordova/phonegap to make a Android app and trying to call JavaScript funtion from android/native

My main acitvity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(Url);

        // TODO call javascripte from here 

    }
}
```

My index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>PhoneGap</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        function myFun(){
          alert("call from the ANDROID");
        }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body >
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want call JavaScript function from phonegap.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716167/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-android-using-phonegap-plugin

Comment: No that is not working :-(   .

Comment: Use PluginResult. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453415/call-javascript-from-cordovaactivity or http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yohpapa/20130819/1376947942, for example.

Answer (score 4):

try this code

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:myFun()");
```

Comment: i am not using webView over here

Comment: @user5716434 then how to run your javascript?

Comment: Please check your entire project app must contain the webview, this loadUrl(Url); is used to load the html file into webview.

Comment: What if I want to get a result from JavaScript function? webView.loadUrl() is void in nature.