# Use callbackContext inside BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, cordova, broadcastreceiver, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova plugin which scans a barcode, using a service named "com.hyipc.core.service.barcode.BarcodeService2D".  This is done by registering a receiver with Broadcast Receiver.

The scanning process runs successfully, but I want to send back to my cordova app the scanning result, which I saw is done using `callbackContext.success(strBarcode)`. The problem is that I cannot use this inside my BarcodeReceiverClass. Is there any way I can send data from inside `onReceive` back to my app?

```
public class Scanner extends CordovaPlugin {

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BarcodeReceiver();
    private Intent intentService = new Intent("com.hyipc.core.service.barcode.BarcodeService2D");
    public static final String ACTION_BARCODE_SERVICE_BROADCAST = "action_barcode_broadcast";
    public static final String KEY_BARCODE_STR = "key_barcode_string";
    private String strBarcode = "";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("scan")) {
            scan();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
    }
}

    public void scan() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_BARCODE_SERVICE_BROADCAST);

        cordova.getActivity().startService(intentService);
        cordova.getActivity().registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);  
    }

    public class BarcodeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_BARCODE_SERVICE_BROADCAST)) {
                strBarcode = intent.getExtras().getString(KEY_BARCODE_STR);
                callbackContext.success(strBarcode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the callback context parameter to you BarcodeReceiver class:

```
public class Scanner extends CordovaPlugin {
   ....
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = null;

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
       ....
       mReceiver = new BarcodeReceiver(callbackContext);
       ....
    }
   ....
}

public class BarcodeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private CallbackContext callbackContext;

    public BarcodeReceiver (CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
    }

    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_BARCODE_SERVICE_BROADCAST)) {
            strBarcode = intent.getExtras().getString(KEY_BARCODE_STR);
            callbackContext.success(strBarcode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a build error: illegal start of expression
            private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BarcodeReceiver(callbackContext);

Comment: Sorry, check my edit up in code, the scope is send parameter callbackContext to BarcodeReceiver class. For make that, you need to add this in constructor of BarcodeReceiver then pass that when instantiate this class from CordovaPlugin child class.

Comment: Yes, now it works, thank you. I'll award your bounty in 21 hours (stackoverflow it doesn't let me do it until than)

Comment: @AlexandruPufan I know this question is answered. But You can also make use of cordova's PluginResult as well. Suggest you check out this link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099912/callback-from-activity-on-cordova/29108349#29108349 Let me know if it was useful

Comment: @Gandhi PluginResult still need callbackContext (callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PlunginResult(..)...) in your link.

Comment: @Frix33 Agreed Frix. But thats an other way to send data back as asked in the question

Comment: how is your plugin.xml?